# Unable to traverse through all the columns of a table Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have created a table using semantic-reactjs. This table has a header and a sub header. The sub header has 6 columns with each cell containing dates of the current week. I make an api call to get date object and based on the response i want to compare the received date with the date in the header, if it matches i want to fill in that corresponding cell with a value, if it does not match, i want to fill with a different value.

If you see the screenshot i want to enter those values against each name and all the dates.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Icon, Table } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import moment from 'moment'

class MyComponent extends Component {

render(){
  let myList = this.props.myList
  let today = moment()
    return(
        <Table celled structured id="table">
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell rowSpan='2' 
   textAlign='center'>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='6' 
   textAlign='center'>Dates</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
          <Table.Row textAlign='center'>
            <Table.HeaderCell>{moment().day(1).format('DD-MM')} . 
  </Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>{moment().day(2).format('DD-MM')} . 
  </Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>{moment().day(3).format('DD-MM')} . 
 </Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>{moment().day(4).format('DD-MM')} . 
 </Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>{moment().day(5).format('DD-MM')} . 
 </Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>{moment().day(6).format('DD-MM')} . 
 </Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body>
          {Object.keys(myList).map(function(key){
            return(
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell>{key}</Table.Cell>

                { myList[key].map(function(object){
                  if(today.isAfter(object.requiredDate)){
                          let table = document.getElementById('table')
                          let requiredDate = 
moment(object.givenDate).format('DD-MM')
                          for(let i = 0 ; i < 
table.rows[1].cells.length; i++){
                                let headerDate = 
table.rows[1].cells[i].innerText
                                  if(requiredDate !== headerDate){
                                    <Table.Cell  textAlign='center'>
                                      <Icon name='question'>
                                      </Icon>
                                      </Table.Cell>
                                    }
                                else{
                                    if(object.state === 'P'){
                                     return(
                                     <Table.Cell>
                                            <Icon color='green' 
         name='check' size='large'/>
                                            {object.state}
                                            </Table.Cell>
                                     )
                                    } else {
                                        return(
                                          <Table.Cell>
                                              <Icon color='red' 
           name='close' size='large' />
                                              {object.state}
                                              </Table.Cell>
                                        )
                                      }
                                }

                            }
                          }
                  })
                }

                </Table.Row>
              )
            })}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>

    )
  }
 }


export default MyComponent
```

I have tried everything that i could think of but its entering the value only in the first column for all the entries.

Any help is much appreciated.

myList Object looks like this,

Thanks,
Vikram
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a working codesandbox or codepen link?

Comment: Why are you using `let table = document.getElementById('table')`? Seems strange to get elements from DOM in order to create this component. Hard to help without a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: what does `myList` looks like?

Comment: So `requiredDate = moment(object.givenDate).format('DD-MM')` is of date type and `headerDate = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerText` is of string type so they never match, I mean `requiredDate !== headerDate` holds for all values. But you are not returning from that if block. So here you got nothing. Let me know if I was right.

Comment: @DineshPandiyan:the api call that i am making is on a localhost server, so perhaps not useful
@charlietfl :I am getting the table component cos i can do table.rows[i].cells.length to get the number of columns i have to iterate, thats the best i could think of,if there's a better way, please suggest. 
@seethrough : `.format` is returning me a string, so the string compare is fine. Lets assume that if it was a mismatch and it never went through the condition,the else part should at least execute. But whats happening is its just putting the values for the first column i.e under the header 28-05

Comment: @VikramMahishi does `today.isAfter(object.requiredDate` hold? I mean for all entries of your spy object? That is your first true-false check

Comment: @seethrough : Yes, i've just added how my `myList` object looks like. So that idea is any data that i get if the date parameter of that sub object is at least today, i want to enter in, other wise ignore. Once i enter in i want to enter the value of that date under that corresponding column.

Comment: You have nested return statements. Is this intended? (may as well split code for clarity)

Comment: @Attersson : I have done that cos i think i have to return every child element to its parent for it to be rendered? Wrong?

Comment: I recommend to split the rendering JSX such that you have a single return () eventually including blocks / JSX

Comment: @Attersson : Sounds a good idea, perhaps i have to split the table cell component into a separate one which just returns me a cell with the passed in data irrespective of the data it gets.
@seethrough: I wrote the above code thinking that with the map function it picks up the first key(person one name), picks up the date of that key object, iterates through the `for` loop inserting cells in the first row which fits my requirement but for some reason it puts in only one cell and then goes through the loop without inserting anymore cells and then advances to the next key and does the same.

Comment: @VikramMahishi Yes go ahead and try that

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I've tested, the main problem is that your condition `if(today.isAfter(object.requiredDate)){` is not complete, as today is before every dates your set into "myList".

Comment: Thats not true, if you look at the screenshot attached, 28-05-2018 is before today, so the result of the conditional is true.

Comment: I tested it, and as we are 27-05-2018, the 28th is after today. Just put a console.log in your if statement and you will see.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've been messing around with dates so much that i forgot whats today.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't compare your object values to the innerText of some table cell elements
2. `requiredDate` does NOT exist in `object` in your object iteration
3. Your myList object format is weird, I am attaching mine in data.js

```
// MyComponent.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import { Icon, Table } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import moment from 'moment'

const dates = Array(6).fill().map((e, i) => moment().day(i+1).format('DD-MM')) 

class MyComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        let myList = this.props.myList
        let today = moment()
        return (
            <Table celled structured id="table">
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell rowSpan='2' textAlign='center'>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='6' textAlign='center'>Dates</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row textAlign='center'>
                        {dates.map((s, i) => <Table.HeaderCell key={i}>{s}</Table.HeaderCell>)}
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body>
                    {Object.keys(myList).map(function (key, j) {
                        return (
                            <Table.Row key={j}>
                                <Table.Cell>{key}</Table.Cell>

                                {myList[key].map(function (object) {
                                    console.log(object)
                                    let requiredDate = moment(object.givenDate, 'DD-MM')
                                    if (today.isAfter(requiredDate)) {
                                        for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                                            let headerDate = dates[i]
                                            let requiredDateStr = object.givenDate
                                            if (requiredDateStr !== headerDate) {
                                                return <Table.Cell textAlign='center'>
                                                    <Icon name='question' />
                                                </Table.Cell>
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                const isP = object.state === 'P'
                                                return <Table.Cell>
                                                    <Icon color={isP? 'green': 'red'} name={isP? 'check': 'close'} size='large' />
                                                    {object.state}
                                                </Table.Cell>
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                    return null
                                })
                                }

                            </Table.Row>
                        )
                    })}
                </Table.Body>
            </Table>

        )
    }
}

export default MyComponent
```

/* data.js */

```
const P = 'P'
export default {
    'Person One': [
        {
            givenDate: '28-05',
            state: P,
            id: 234,
        },
        {
            givenDate: '29-05',
            state: P,
            id: 234
        },
        {
            givenDate: '29-05',
            state: P,
            id: 234/*  */
        },
    ],
    'Person Two': [
        {
            givenDate: '28-05',
            state: P,
            id: 234
        },
        {
            givenDate: '29-05',
            state: P,
            id: 234
        },
        {
            givenDate: '30-05',
            state: P,
            id: 234
        },
    ],
    'Person Three': [
        {
            givenDate: '28-05',
            state: P,
            id: 234
        },
        {
            givenDate: '29-05',
            state: P,
            id: 234
        },
        {
            givenDate: '30-05',
            state: P,
            id: 234
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: btw if you want to give it a test, try changing `let today = moment()` to something like `let today = moment('2018-06-02')`, for example so you can see what it actually looks like on a given date.

Comment: This surely seems to be a much better approach, but `if (today.isAfter(requiredDate))` is evaluating to true till the month number changes. So i have the`Person One` array containing 5 objects with the givenDates for each object as 28-05, 29-05, 31-05, 01-06, 02-02. As per the code it should insert a cell only under 28-5 but its also inserting under 29 and 30 and i don't get it. And if the check has failed why insert only the next 2 cells, it should continue inserting for all the 5 dates. I have attached screen shots of the same.

Comment: I got it that its already inside the loop which has passed the `if` check, and the for loop is incrementing the header dates, but shouldn't it add the cells and data for all the 6 cells instead of just 2?